# Send data over sockets from Java program to C program

Tags: java, c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send data over network from a Java program to a C program.
But I don't know which type of data to use. I tried with a char.

Here is my Java code :

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
char c = 'c';
dos.writeChar(c);
```

And my C code :

```
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer, 256);
read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
printf("Here is the message: %c\n", buffer[0]);
```

"Here is the message" print nothing. I don't know if buffer[0] is empty or if the type is not compatible.

Comment: Yes I can use Json, but I just have an Int so send. I think it would be too heavy and complicated just for that, isn't ?

Comment: Do you check for error? What does `read` return?

Comment: How about: OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream(); os.write((byte) c);

Comment: There is no error with read, I checked it

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return value of `read`? How many bytes did you receive?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Yes it works ! Thanks !

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not ignoring the return value. I deleted it for the post. I have it in my program.

Comment: I think DataOutputSteam is a Wrapper for easy communication for Java. To communicate with another program of different language, it would better to use the most primitive stream.

Comment: @LucasPierrat: Well, what was it?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi I think too, but I only knew DataOutputStream.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB read returns 1

Comment: You do know that a C `char` is a Java `byte`, right?

Comment: No, I didn't know.. But now yes.

Comment: If `read()` returns -1 you should have called `perror()` or its friends to tell us what the error was, and you should have posted what the error was in your qiestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in java a char is two bytes, you may use the java type "byte" to just send one byte. Or you have to support the two-byte character (unicode) sent by Java, to be printed in C.

Yet I did not have the time to check the rest of your code, but this might be a start.